# How to extract certain elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The below code accesses and array with objects in it. Each object has and id, an url and a Tag. I want to be able to basically use the Tag to display a random URL connected with a tag I suggest.

For example i want window.currentlyShownOffer.Tag to always be equal to Garden. Garden is a Tag.

```
function receivedData(data) {

        function changeOfferPicture() {
            if (window.currentlyShownOffer) {
                var tagArray = data[window.currentlyShownOffer.Tag];
                tagArray.splice(tagArray.indexOf(currentlyShownOffer), 1);
                //alert(window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesId);

            }


            var tags = Object.keys(data);
            var randomTag = tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)];
            var tagArray = data[randomTag];


            window.currentlyShownOffer = tagArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * tagArray.length)];
            document.getElementById('content').src = window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesPath;
        };
}
```

Any idea of what the array looks like:

```
{“Garden”:[{“ImagesId”:”63”,”ImagesPath”:”http….”,”Tag”:”Garden”},{“Garden”:[{“ImagesId”:”64”,”ImagesPath”:”http….”,”Tag”:”Garden”}]{“Food”:[{“ImagesId”:”63”,”ImagesPath”:”http….”,”Tag”:”Food”},{“Food”:[{“ImagesId”:”63”,”ImagesPath”:”http….”,”Tag”:”Food”}]
```

UPDATE

```
function receivedData(data) {

        function changeOfferPicture() {
            if (window.currentlyShownOffer) {
                var tagArray = data[window.currentlyShownOffer.Tag];
                tagArray.splice(tagArray.indexOf(currentlyShownOffer), 1);
                //alert(window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesId);

            }


            var tags = Object.keys(data);
            var randomTag = tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)];
            var tagArray = data[randomTag];

         function getObjectsWithTag(tag, tagArray){
                return tagArray.filter(function(item){
                return item.tag === tag;
            });
            }

            getObjectsWithTag(Garden);


            window.currentlyShownOffer = tagArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * tagArray.length)];
            document.getElementById('content').src = window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesPath;
        };
}
```

Here's maybe a better idea of the array:

```
{
“Garden’ : [{‘ImagesId”: ”38”, ”ImagesPath”: ”url”, ”Tag”: ”Food”}],
“Sport’: [{‘ImagesId”: ”64”, ”ImagesPath”: ”url”, ”Tag”: ”Sport”}]
}
```

Comment: You can access/find items in the array using indexOf() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: okay, so what's not working in this code that you think should work? I'm not seeing an actual question, you're more hinting that "something" is wrong, which isn't quite enough information

Comment: This piece of code is giving me a random url from all the Tags. I want to just get a random url from just the ones that have Tag: Garden

Comment: updated my code to the most recent example

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get all items with a specific `tag`. If `tagArray` has Objects with a key `tag` containing the tag name:

```
function getObjectsWithTag(tag, tagArray){
  return tagArray.filter(function(item){
    return item.tag === tag;
  });
}
```

The returned value will be an array containing only items that matched the tag name in the original `tagArray`.

Comment: Thank you, I 'm new to this and I'm struggling to implement what you are suggesting.. I added an update to my code above with what I have.

Comment: Take a look at your sample array again. There are mismatched brackets, which make it difficult to understand...

Comment: I added maybe a better idea of the array under the updated code

Comment: Re-do the whole question, presenting a good example of your data and what needs to be extracted from your data, without your the code. Right now, it's just getting more confusing and too specific to your application.